# Keep records with Spanish accents in Database using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, spell-checking, diacritics

I need to purge a DataBase that is in Spanish but the requirement is that I must keep accent marks.

For instance, if the DB contains "Administración" and "Administracion" I have to identify them as equals but keep the one with the accent mark. After some research every solution, like turn Unicode to ASCII or use PyEnchant, keeps the one without the accent mark.

Is there any Library (For Python 3.5) or way to determine the correct one and keep it?

Comment: Once you run your converter on the two inputs, one of them should match the output and the other shouldn't.  So just keep the one that doesn't match the sanitized output.

Comment: What database are you using? Maybe could be an issue with the databas's driver. For example, when using MySql you should explicitly pass the enconding format that you are using

Comment: Doubt if downgrading to ASCII is the right choice in the long run. I would probably try my best to keep all in UTF8. If your locale is part of the database I assume that you are dealing with CMS data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Caveats

Depending on the content of the database, this may well be a nontrivial task, since though there may be misspellings:

- *`administracion` `administración`

There are also many pairs of words in Spanish which differ only by an accent, but which both are valid words:

- `ejército` `ejercito` `ejercitó` | `tu` `tú`

If you are only considering nouns, this number decreases a lot, mostly to [foreign loanwords](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26156/18348) with different stresses:

- `beisbol` `béisbol`

and a few native words [multiple spellings](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26177/18348):

- `período` `periodo` | `reúma` `reuma`

---

## Query

If you are unlikely to encounter such cases, you could use a sql query along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT a.word AS "Good word", b.word AS "Bad word"
FROM   spanish_db AS a
JOIN   spanish_db AS b

--Spanish words have at most one accent so can safely nest REPLACE
ON     REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.word, "á", "a"), 
                                                       "é", "e"), 
                                                       "í", "i"), 
                                                       "ó", "o"), 
                                                       "u", "u") = b.word

--So as not to match identical words
AND    a.word != b.word
```

This will return all pairs of words where an accented and unaccented form appear. You can adapt this to edit/delete/cleanse the entries as is required.

---

## Example

```
Good word       Bad word
"acedía"        "acedia"
"aeróbic"       "aerobic"
"aeróstato"     "aerostato"
"afrodisíaco"   "afrodisiaco"
"alcalá"        "alcala"
"alvéolo"       "alveolo"
"alérgeno"      "alergeno"
"amoníaco"      "amoniaco"
"anémona"       "anemona"
"arcén"         "arcen"
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about indexing your database queries in a dict, by their ascii equivilent? Assumeing there is only one forms of an ascii key:

```
def ascii_word(word):
   accents=(("á","a"), ("é","e"), ("í","i"), ("ó","o"), ("ú","u"), ("ü","u"), ("ñ","n"))
   for acc in accents: word=word.replace(acc[0],acc[1])
   return word

query_result = ["Administración", "Administracion", "si", "sí", "hola"]
filtered_dict={}

for s in query_result:
   ascii=ascii_word(s)
   if ascii in filtered_dict.keys(): 
      if s!=ascii: filtered_dict[ascii] = s
  else:
      filtered_dict[ascii] = s

  result=list(filtered_dict.values())
  print(result)
```

This prints to `['Administración', 'sí', 'hola']`